# Remove "Recommended for you" from YouTube related video sidebar?

Tags: youtube

Is there a way to keep the list of related videos to the one you are currently watching, but not include the ones that recommended to me based on my own watch and search history?

For example, I have interests in both science and soccer YouTube clips. When watching a science video I will get a mix of videos on the related videos tab that actually are related to the video I am currently watching, with a mix of soccer and sports videos that are relevant to my interests, but not the video.

Is there a way to then remove these "recommended videos", but not from the YouTube homepage, but from the related video sidebar?

Answer (score 2):

There are several browser extensions that remove this and/or other elements, if you so choose to.

I use the Magic Actions for YouTube extension, that allows disabling recommended videos under Options > Hide Page Elements. It is available for [Google Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/abjcfabbhafbcdfjoecdgepllmpfceif/), [Mozilla Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/magic-actions-for-youtube) and [Opera](https://addons.opera.com/extensions/details/magic-actions-for-youtube/).